# SQL Server : insert into fails because of entity insert is off

Tags: sql-server

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my code

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Erea_Local].[Domain].[BlikAfmeting] ON

INSERT INTO [Erea_Local].[Domain].[BlikAfmeting] 
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[BlikAfmetings] 

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [Erea_Local].[Domain].[BlikAfmeting] OFF
```

This is the error

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Erea_Local.Domain.BlikAfmeting' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

If I only run the set `IDENTITY INSERT .....`

I get the message command completed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the message:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table
>   'Erea_Local.Domain.BlikAfmeting' can only be specified **when a column
>   list is used** and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

You should use a column list of values.

Comment: Note to myself read the full error instead of just the last 3 words.